# Select option still appears on the page even after PHP IF.. statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, select-options

I'm developing an Online Store with PHP, so at the `productdetails.php` which shows the details of products, I coded this:

```
if(!empty($pro_colors))
{
echo "
    <div class=''>
        <h4 class='' style='float:right'>&nbsp;:رنگ <span>*</span></h4>
        <select class='select-css'>      
        ";
        foreach($pro_colors as $colors)
        {
            echo "
                <option value='$colors'>$colors</option>
            ";                                          
        }
        echo "
        </select>
    </div></br>
";
}
```

So simply what it should do is that, if any color has been added to the product at db, it has to show the select option and if no color has been added to the db, the select option must not appear!

But when there is not data on db as color, it shows this:

[image]

However, my table looks like this:

[image]

So please tell me, how should I solve this problem ?!

Comment: Check the contents of the variable your using `var_dump($pro_colors);`

Comment: Adding to what @NigelRen said, in the pic of the table, `product_colors` appears to be empty but it may contain a space character which makes the `empty` call fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your array `$pro_colors` has an empty value. You can clean empty and null values from your array using [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$pro_colors = array_filter($pro_colors);

if(!empty($pro_colors))
{
echo "
    <div class=''>
        <h4 class='' style='float:right'>&nbsp;:رنگ <span>*</span></h4>
        <select class='select-css'>      
        ";
        foreach($pro_colors as $colors)
        {
            echo "
                <option value='$colors'>$colors</option>
            ";                                          
        }
        echo "
        </select>
    </div></br>
";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether color is empty or not. like this

```
      foreach($pro_colors as $colors)
        {

if (!empty($colors)) {
            echo "
                <option value='$colors'>$colors</option>
            ";  
                      }

        }
```

You have used if(!empty($pro_colors)) first actually it does not check each color as $pro_colors is an array.

EDIT: As per @hasta dhana comment. First you need to check whether database has any color data or not. As you have not full code i'm writing this sample code so that you understand:

```
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM tablenamehere WHERE product_colors != ''"; 
    $result = $con->prepare($sql); 
    $result->execute(); 
    $number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn(); 

if ($number_of_rows > 0 ) {

echo "
    <div class=''>
        <h4 class='' style='float:right'>&nbsp;:رنگ <span>*</span></h4>
        <select class='select-css'>      
        ";
          foreach($pro_colors as $colors)
        {

if (!empty($colors)) {
            echo "
                <option value='$colors'>$colors</option>
            ";  
                      }

        }
        echo "
        </select>
    </div></br>
";
}
```

Comment: Using this approach will still display the select since the `<select class='select-css'>` element is still outside of the `if` conditional

Comment: exactly @HastaDhana, in that case he have to check whether database has any color or not. it must be done after sql query. as he did not give the query and full code i cant give him the full working code. however i will edit the ans and add row idea there. thanks for pointing it our